# Atributo":SRC" não esta funcionando no Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Olá gostaria de entender pq o ":SRC" não esta funcionando no vue js, tentei colocar renderizar uma imagem que possui seu caminho dentro da propriedade "img", porém simplesmente não funciona.

tag imagem:

```
<img :src="img" />
```

propriedade:

```
data: () => ({
    img: '../assets/imgs/teste.png'    
})
```

,

**Observação:** o caminho esta correto, e quando eu coloco este caminho na propriedade SRC estática funciona assim:

```
<img src="../assets/imgs/teste.png" />
```

Alguém sabe me dizer oque há de errado?

Comment: assim funciona? img:  require('../assets/imgs/teste.png')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É recomendando no vue que você use a função require() do webpack para arquivos estático.(https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html)

Ficaria assim

```
<img :src="require(img)" alt="" />
```